# Standardized pareto Chart in R

Tags: r, charts, standardized, pareto-chart

I have been looking for ways to plot a standardized Pareto chart in R but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. An example of the chart is below:
[Pareto Chart of Standardized Effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGShw.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This type of question is better often typed into http://rseek.org. I did that for you. Check out the `qualityTools` package

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look